# postMessage into object tag

Tags: html, postmessage, object-tag

I am trying to get the html inside an object respond to my postMessage, but I am unable to get the referencing correct.

I've tried

```
var object = $("#test_object").get(0).contentWindow;
object.postMessage("run","*");
```

which works for iframe.

But as i am determined to use the object tag. Is there a way to pass the postMessage through?

Answer (score 0):

No, postMessage works only for iframes and windows/tabs.

Comment: You can do `objectEl.contentDocument.defaultView.postMessage(...)`. But you need to be in the same origin (same protocol, port and host) of the object's content to access to its document (`objectEl.contentDocument`). If you use `postMessage` that means it's not, so it's useless.