# Can an IFrame be forced to render in IE9 Document mode when the parent is in Quirks mode?

Tags: iframe

I am working with a legacy third party site that allows me to add HTML to a container. The site will then show this HTML. I current have one of these containers hosting the following HTML

`<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<iframe id="the_id" src="http://blahblah.blah" width="100%" Height="640px"></iframe>`

Since the third party site is legacy, it renders in Quirks mode. (If I try to force it into a different mode, the site does not load.)

The site contained in the IFrame, however is a modern site that uses a lot of CSS. Unfortunately, the CSS will not render when the parent is in Quirks mode. Can someone tell me if it is possible to force my IFrame to render in IE9 Document mode?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467151/iframe-not-rendering-in-ie9-mode-when-containing-page-is-in-quirks-mode

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately it does not work.