# How to force Iframe to run IE=edge mode under parent page running in IE=EmulateIE7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe

I am working on app what is running on IE=Emulated7 (running fine) but now I have to add a iframe to load a external app( SPA app). Everything could be okay if I could change the next lines in my "parent" page...

FROM

```
<meta runat="server" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

TO

```
<meta  runat="server" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

BUT I can't because there are other pages that needs have this IE7 mode.

I tried add IE=edge to my child page where iframe will be located, but doesn't works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta id="OtherAppCompatibilityMeta" runat="server" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"  content="IE=edge" />
     <script>
    console.log("Iframe document mode: " + document.documentMode);
     </script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
       html, body{height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
      <iframe id="myId" runat="server" allowfullscreen="true"  style="position: absolute;height: 100%; width: 100%;border:0px"> </iframe>  
    </div>
</form>
```

From the header section, the output of document.documentMode is: "Iframe document mode: 11", So that is very strange for me.
As I said before, Everything should be easier I could change the "parent" page to use Iframe document mode: 11 but i can't.

Comment: This is [not possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `"As of IE9 mode, webpages cannot display multiple document modes."`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe not rendering in ie9 mode when containing page is in quirks mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467151/iframe-not-rendering-in-ie9-mode-when-containing-page-is-in-quirks-mode)