# IE9 - Is it possible to have a child Frame render in Edge (HTML5) while parent Frames are in Quirks mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

I am working on an web project that is a parent container unfortunately made up of several framesets / frames (I have no control over this). The overall document mode is Quirks, since several of the peripheral frames use non-standard doctypes. I am working on a page that is going to be used in one of the frames that needs to have HTML5 enabled (`<!doctype html>`). However, IE9 is commenting out the doctype in this frame, and rendering it in Quirks also.

Is there any way for me to force this particular frame to render in HTML5 standards mode, while the parent container is still in Quirks mode?

**EDIT**: I found this StackOverflow question from 2012: [iframe not rendering in ie9 mode when containing page is in quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467151/iframe-not-rendering-in-ie9-mode-when-containing-page-is-in-quirks-mode). Is this still the only possible solution? I really don't want to use this solution as using an `<object>` tag makes it very hard to debug with F12 dev tools (all that will be seen is just the `<object>` tag, and not the HTML contained within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a document is loaded in Quirks mode, all of its iframes will be as well. For more information, please see [2.1.2.3 iframe Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as well as the following diagram:

[image]

With regards to the suggested work-around (using `<object>`), we're aware that debugging this approach can be difficult. You can however debug the same document in another tab for the time being. Please note the other serious limitations of that work-around in both [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521317/54680) and the subsequent comments.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. So it appears that using `<object>` is essentially the ONLY solution, right? As for the serious limitations you mentioned, from what I can tell, it's in regards to lack of support in IE10, right? If so, it's ok since this web app is IE8/9 only as of now.

Comment: Also, as for debugging, I noticed that browsers such as Chrome correctly display the embedded HTML of the `<object>` in F12. Is there any way to get IE9 to also display the embedded HTML in F12?

Comment: @Amberite Not presently; the approach of using `<object>` as a replacement for `<iframe>` is very, very uncommon in my experience. As a result, it's not a scenario that is presently supported in the IE Developer Tools. I have brought it up in meetings though, and hope to see it added in further builds.